# Need Separator image for views ticker content?

Tags: views, 7

I am using [Views Ticker](http://drupal.org/project/views_ticker) module for display the news in my site. It's perfectly worked for me. I want separator image for one content to another content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants the separator between two content you have to write css for that.This is a css query.Please check the css.Have a great day.